# Required background modes iOS6 Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I've noticed that in Xcode 4.5 and iOS6 'required background modes' - 'app plays audio' doesn't work!

Has anybody else noticed this if so have you found a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: If your problem is with audio in UIWebView, then the answer is at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background/12414719). Otherwise, I have no problem with background audio in iOS 6.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes the audio is in a UIWebView, a great help.

Comment: This answered my question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background/12414719

Thanks again Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can be dependent upon the type of category you specify for the AVAudioSession... Ensure it is set to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` when initializing your session.

Comment: It's coming through a UIWebView, worked fine in 5.1 then in 6 stopped working!... Anyway, works fine now thanks to Chris's help.