# Play video in UIWebview background on Airplay

Tags: ios, airplay, apple-tv

I have an app that plays several webvideos like Youtube and Vimeo in a UIWebView. When the video plays it is possible to send it to an Apple TV over AirPlay.

Currently, during playback over AirPlay the video stops when I pause the app and move it to the background.

**My desired result is that the video will keep playing on the Apple TV.**

After some research I found out that I have to set the `Required background modes` in the Info.plist to `App plays audio`. Unfortunately this did not work.

So what does need to be set to keep the video playing over AirPlay when the app is moved to the background.

Comment: i simply set `webView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = YES;` and `Required background modes` to YES, and it works. is there anything you did differently?

Comment: I put mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay to yes and set Required background modes to App plays audio. But still when I put the app to the background it stops playing.

Comment: Ok I tested it on iOS 5 now and that worked like described above. For iOS 6 doesn't work. Does iOS 6 require more other settings?

Comment: I've only tested the method on iOS6 and it worked. But it seems to mess with UIWebView, maybe you can check [Required background modes iOS6 Xcode 4.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603294/required-background-modes-ios6-xcode-4-5) which refers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background/12414719)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i've tested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background/12414719) on iOS6 with UIWebView loading video webpage, and it does the job. the audio session needed to be set as `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` in order to be played in background.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting the audio session category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` is all that is necessary, to make AirPlay work properly from a video inside a `UIWebView`. The video continues to play on Airplay even after the device goes to sleep. The `mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay` property is YES by default.