# iOS 6 UIWebView video with no sound

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios6

Our app hosts HTML in UIWebView. Few of our users have noticed that the videos no longer play audio, all in iOS 6. I have researched this issue and can't duplicate the bug however the user complaints continue to pour in. Initially I assumed that the user had accidentally muted their device, however it doesn't seem to be the case.

Has anyone here noticed any similar issues?

Comment: The answer at the following should fix your issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background

Comment: Thanks AndyDev , that solution worked. I must add that this issue is with some iPhone/iPad's

Comment: Thanks for pointing us out to the other thread. Works like a charm :D