# Audio no longer playing in background on iOS 6 in Phonegap project

Tags: audio, cordova, ios6, multitasking

I need audio running in the background for my application. In versions before iOS 6 this worked perfectly by adding the

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

code to the appropriate .plist file, however this no longer works when deploying my phonegap project to iOS 6. How can I fix this in iOS 6?

Comment: I have found a similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background#comment17805618_12414719 but I have no experience with XCode so I'm not sure how to make this work. I pasted the code in the MainController.m file under // custom initialisation, but then my app hangs when launching. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just want to point out that this also effects how audio plays when the ringer is off. Normally, HTML5 audio element in a UIWebView will only play if the ringer is on. Following the steps described in the answer will allow audio to play when the ringer is off.

Answer (score 2):

In the MainController.h file change the following:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation MainViewController

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm not sure if the following is necessary but I cleaned my project (CMD+ALT+K), recompiled the PhoneGap / Cordova Lib (change target and let it run to simulator) and (after changing the target again) compiled to the application once more and now it works!

**Beware**: it only works on Device, not on the simulator