# Is there a way to select the audio output when playing HTML5 sound on ios

Tags: ios, html, html5-audio

I'm playing some sound using HTML5 audio API on iOS.

Unfortunately sound seems to play through the top speaker, not the main one.

Is there a way to select an output for my sound?

Comment: You might dig in the direction of kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute (require a native application with a UIWebview).

Comment: See accepted response here for more informations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background