# Phonegap - play local audio when phone is locked iOS 6

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, playback, standby

I am building an app using PhoneGap that needs to be able to play local .mp3 files even though the phone is locked/standby. 
The audio player is build in HTML5, and is working fine, but the music stops when I either close the app or turn off the phone.

I tried following the answer given in this link
[UIWebView: HTML5 audio pauses in iOS 6 when app enters background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background/12414719#12414719)

But no luck...

I did the import code at the top with the other import functions.  And I also included the AVFoundation framework to my target.

This is how the code looks in the AppDelegate.m

```
/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here. (preferred -iOS4 and up)
 */
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

    /* THE GOOD STUFF */
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL ok;
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    ok = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                         error:&setCategoryError];
    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"%s setCategoryError=%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, setCategoryError);
    }
```

I tried in simulator and on iPhone 5.

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you have to set your audio category in your app_name-info.plist  [image: App Audio Category]

Then use the phonegap API media player 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.play

```
function playAudio(url) {
// Play the audio file at url
var my_media = new Media(url,
    // success callback
    function() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },
    // error callback
    function(err) {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: "+err);
});

// Play audio
my_media.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : true });
```

Notice the `playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked` defaults to true anyways.

Also note in the Simulator the Audio will never work in background, so you will need to test on a device.

Please mark as Answered if this helped ?

Comment: The audio is already playing fine, and I did not use the phonegap API. I tried once and it didn't work. Do I have to use it in order for the audio to play in the background?
Thanks for your answer!