# How to play video in background using UIWebView on iOS 7

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube iframe_api to play a video in UIWebView on iOS 7, when I click Home button the app goes to background, the video is paused.
Is there a way to let the audio of video continue playing in background?

Comment: Check this answer it might help
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12414719/3085086