# Cordova Media Plugin vs HTML5 Audio

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

My Cordova app currently has two ways to play audio, one works on the web app and one works on the cross-platform native app.

- **HTML5 for Web** HTML: `<audio id="audio" src="audio.mp3"></audio>` JS: `document.getElementById('audio').play();`
- **Cordova Plugin for Mobile** JS `new Media('audio.mp3').play();`

I'm not a fan of writing things twice.  Is there an audio solution that works for both web and mobile?  Or an elegant way to fallback?

Comment: Could you please share the code to play the audio file on Ionic App on Device? I am getting "Media is not defined." please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used both the media plugin, and HTML5 audio in Cordova apps.

https://github.com/devgeeks/ExampleHTML5AudioStreaming

The Audio element is [fairly well supported on mobile](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio).

Comment: Your answer works great  "new Audio('audio.mp3').play();"  Thanks!

Comment: No Working when app is deployed to mobile phone. Please help.

Comment: I can get HTML5 Audio to work fine on mobile. the biggest issue is background audio or playing audio while the screen is locked. HTML5 version doesnt support that

Comment: @Daniel_Madain - iOS can play HTML5 audio in the background, it just needs a little change to the native stuffs... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background/12414719#12414719

Comment: Does someone know if I can work with promises like Cordova Media plugin? I can just get the success callback from the `new Audio().play()` function. But just that promise.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution here that works with the cordova media plugin on devices and the code to emulate it in browsers:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-play-local-audio-files/7479/5

.k

Answer (score 0):

I released a Ionic/Angular module that interfaces with Cordova Media to play audio files.
More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30018460/1964599

You can find the module here: https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio