# Audio player for Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, audio

I am learning Ionic and want to embed an audio player. I have found this Plnkr example of [Video Player](http://plnkr.co/edit/C9vWoszT3FmfcATmZZ81?p=preview):

```
    angular.module('app',[])

.directive('youtubeIframe', ['$timeout', function ($timeout, $sce ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout( function () {
                var temp1 = '<iframe width="400px" height="200px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
                var temp2 = '?&autoplay=0&autohide=1&fs=1&cc_load_policy=1&loop=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&&hd=1&playsinline=0&showinfo=0&theme=light" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                var finalvar = temp1 + attrs.youtubeIframe + temp2 ;
                console.log('Finalvar is: ' + finalvar); //just to check if url is ok
                element.prepend( finalvar );
            }, 150);
            // The timeout is to give enough time for the Dom to be built and checked for its structure, so that we can manipulate it.
        }
    };
}])



.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.angularvideos = [
      { 
        name: 'Angular on the go: Using Angular to power Mobile Apps', 
        youtubeId: 'xOAG7Ab_Oz0',
        publishdate: 'Dec 2013'
      },
      { 
        name: 'Crafting the Perfect AngularJS Model and Making it Real Time', 
        youtubeId: 'lHbWRFpbma4',
        publishdate: 'April 2014'
      },
      { 
        name: 'AngularJS & D3: Directives for Visualizations', 
        youtubeId: 'aqHBLS_6gF8',
        publishdate: 'Jan 2014'
      },
      { 
        name: 'The Thick Front End', 
        youtubeId: 'hv2NEW0uC1o',
        publishdate: 'Nov 2013'
      }
    ];
})
```

Is there a similar example for an audio player within iframe for a mobile App (Android for the time being, but later on iOS as well)?

Answer (score 3):

I released a Ionic module that plays audio natively (tested it on Android so far) using the Cordova Media plugin.

You define a Ionic view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Music">
  <ion-content>
      <ion-audio-track track="myTrack">
          <div class="list list-inset">
              <div class="item item-thumbnail-left">
                  <img src="{{track.art}}">
                  <h2>{{track.title}}</h2>
                  <p>{{track.artist}}</p>
                  <ion-audio-play></ion-audio-play>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <ion-audio-progress-bar display-time></ion-audio-progress-bar>
              </div>
          </div>
      </ion-audio-track>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And your scope:

```
$scope.myTrack = {
    url: 'https://www.example.com/my_song.mp3',
    artist: 'Somebody',
    title: 'Song name',
    art: 'img/album_art.jpg'
}
```

Looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

You can find it here: https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio

Comment: Will it work in browser? I have checked in browser but working

Comment: No, you need the Cordova Media plugin installed on your device. I am working on a fallback to use Web Audio API on the browser, but it isn't ready yet!

Comment: Great!! It's worked fine in emulator. It would be great if you can add `volume`, `next/prev track` options.

Answer (score 2):

I think right thing is available there- links:

[Dev-friendly and stable module for audio, html5-video, youtube(iframe) etc..](http://www.videogular.com/examples/)

Here is [Example](http://www.videogular.com/examples/creating-an-audio-player/) creating Audio Player.

Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/2fdevs/pen/tguGx)

```
    <videogular vg-theme="controller.config.theme.url" class="videogular-container audio">
    <vg-media vg-src="controller.config.sources"></vg-media>

    <vg-controls>
        <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
        <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
        <vg-scrub-bar>
            <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
        </vg-scrub-bar>
        <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
        <vg-volume>
            <vg-mute-button></vg-mute-button>
        </vg-volume>
    </vg-controls>
</videogular>
```

Comment: I actually started with videogular and ran into problems. Even the above date filter falls apart if I replace mm:ss with hh:mm:ss due to time zone issues.