# Video sound not playing in IPhone in silent mode? How to fix the same?

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Video sound not playing in IPhone in silent mode? How to fix the same? When in silent mode the video sound is on mute. This is a hybrid app for IOS created with Phonegap. When the Iphone is switched to normal mode the video sound plays properly.

Comment: If the iPhone is in silent mode, the obvious behaviour is that nothing have sound. What do you expect?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Then the behaviour should be common to all the app and should not be app specific. For Youtube sound plays in silent mode as well. So just wanted to know what is the proper behaviour?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28334865/14131

Comment: did you found a solution for this . This is a very interesting question